# Is there a way to trigger a copy via command line that uses the progress dialog on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, command-line

I'm writing a batch job that needs to copy a directory of database backups from a network drive to the local machine.

When I manually move these files in Windows 8 I get a nice copy dialog that shows the overall progress.

I can automate this process using Xcopy, but the copy takes a very long time and there's no feedback to show that anything is in progress.

Is there any command that can be used on Win8 that will trigger a copy and display the progress dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Use ROBOCOPY instead of XCOPY

`ROBOCOPY /?`

There's also a custom PowerShell function that a user wrote on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883404/custom-robocopy-progress-bar-in-powershell).

Comment: It's important to note here that Robocopy will not open the GUI progress dialog, but it WILL return lines in the command prompt window itself, as well as offer logging options.

Answer (score 1):

[RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) is ROBOCOPY wrapped in a GUI. It shows the progress of the file copy in detail, allows saving and loading of options, and is somewhat easier to get started with.

[image]